# How to set a screen resolution other than what is displayed in the scaled list?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I need to set my screen resolution 1280x720 (this is a requirement for a screencast I need to create).  When I go into the Display - Scaled menu this is no longer available as an option on Yosemite, even though it was available on previous versions of the OS on the same laptop.

Is there a way in Yosemite to access or force different screen resolutions for this?

Comment: and this does not work for you ...Apple menu > System Preferences, click Displays, then click Display. • Press the Option key while you click Scaled to see additional resolutions ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install John Ford's screenresolution utility via `brew install screenresolution`. Alternatively you can download and compile the [source here](https://github.com/jhford/screenresolution).

Once the utility is installed you can see *all* available resolutions via `screenresolution list`. Assuming the appropriate resolution is listed you can set your display with something like `screenresolution set 1280x720x32`.

Comment: Q-This is a tool that can be used to determine current resolution,
list available resolutions and set resolutions for active displays
on Mac OS 10.6, and possibly above.  I have only tested 10.6. EQ

Comment: Unfortunately in 2020 the screenresolution tool doesn't work on my 16" MacBook Pro. It can get the current resolution but cannot set it.